# git: how to one local repo synchronize to multiple remote servers?

Tags: git

Please tell me if there is a way git one local repo to synchronize to multiple remote servers?

I want one local repo to pull on github and gitlab and that they are identical to each other

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+push+multiple+remotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure as many [remotes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) as you like and then push or fetch each of them, e.g.

```
git remote add gitlab url-to-your-gitlab/project/repo.git
git remote add github github.com/username/repo.git
git remote add private your-private-server/repo.git
git fetch gitlab
git push private master:master
```